# Oracle filter results by limit

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle and was hoping someone could help me.
I have this stored procedure:

```
procedure ListCatalogues(P_CUR out sys_refcursor,
                         P_CATALOGUENAME varchar2 default '%',
                         P_LIMIT number,
                         P_MEMBERS number default -1) is

begin
     open P_CUR for
        select * 
          from (  select h.catalogueid                           id,
                         h.cataloguename                         name,
                         case 
                         when h.uniquecatalogue = 'N' 
                         then 1 
                         else 0 
                         end                                     includeproducts,
                         case
                         when h.active = 'Y' 
                         then 1 
                         else 0 
                         end                                     active,
                         case
                         when h.ownbrandedlabels = 'Y' 
                         then 1 
                         else 0 
                         end                                     ownlabels,
                         (  select count(*) 
                              from cc_custprofiles t 
                             where t.catalogueid = h.catalogueid
                         )                                       members                 

                    from cc_ob_catalogueheader h

                   where upper(h.cataloguename) like upper('%'||P_CATALOGUENAME||'%')
                     and (select count(*) from cc_custprofiles t where t.catalogueid = h.catalogueid) >= P_MEMBERS

                order by h.catalogueid
               ) 

         where rownum <= P_LIMIT;

end ListCatalogues;
```

As you can see, it accepts a `P_LIMIT` parameter which allows for limiting the results returned. This is fine, but I want to expand on it a little.

If the limit is 10, then return 10 rows, but if the limit is 0, return everything. Can someone help me change the query to match my criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this after a bit of looking around:

```
where rownum <= case when P_LIMIT = 0 then rownum else P_LIMIT end;
```